# SCJP/OCPJP 7 objectives

Tags: java, certificate, scjp, ocpjp

Which are the new objectives added for SCJP/OCPJP 7?
Or to be more specific what are the changes between SCJP/OCPJP 6 and 7?

**PS:** I am not sure if it is still called as SCJP.

---

EDIT : I have added a [post](http://www.ajinkyaparakh.com/2012/01/changesimprovements-added-to-oracle.html) for new changes / objectives added to OCPJP 7.

Comment: Apparently it's called Oracle Certified Professional Java SE Programmer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get all details from here:

http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=319

http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_org_id=&lang=&p_exam_id=1Z0_803